# Como posso aplicar informações do banco no modal?

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, pdo, modal

Bom, estou trabalhando no meu TCC de informática e o intuito dele é controlar a saída de alunos. Consegui fazer sistema de registro, exclusão, já estou trabalhando na edição, porém eu gostaria de implementar um botão que ao clicar, irá mostrar mais informações do aluno dentro de um modal. Eu até consegui fazer isso, porém só aparece o primeiro registro, exemplo:

A tabela contem Ana e Wilian. Caso eu clique para ver os dados da Ana, vai aparecer tudo bonitinho, caso eu clique no Wilian, irá aparecer os dados da Ana. Caso eu inverta e coloque Wilian e depois Ana, somente os dados do Wilian irão aparecer.

PS.: Eu pesquisei bastante p tentar uma solução, porém estou no início do php e aprendi apenas a classe PDO, então me confundo facil com o php "puro" (se é que posso chamar assim).

```
<head>
    <title>MODAL</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!--ARQUIVOS PADRÕES BOOTSTRAP-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

     <?php include("action_usuario.php")?>

    <div class="main register-form col-md-12">

        <ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item">
                <fieldset>
                    <form action="" method="get" id='form-contato' class="form-horizontal col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                        <div class='col-lg-6 col-md-7 col-sm-9 col-lg-offset-2 col-xs-12'>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="termo" name="termo" placeholder="Infome o Nome/Matrícula">
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary col-lg-offset-0 col-xs-offset-2">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>&nbsp;
                        </button>
                        <a href='index.php' class="btn btn-primary">Ver Todos</a>
                    </form>
                </fieldset>
            </li>

            <li class="list-group-item">
                <?php if(!empty($usuarios)):?>

                    <!-- Tabela de Clientes -->
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover ">
                        <tr class='active'>
                            <th>Nome</th>
                            <th>Matrícula</th>
                            <th>Turma</th>
                            <th>Nível</th>
                            <th>Opções</th>
                        </tr>
                        <?php foreach($usuarios as $usuario):?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?=$usuario->nome?></td>
                            <td><?=$usuario->matricula?></td>
                            <td><?=$usuario->turma?></td>
                            <td><?=$usuario->nivel?></td>
                            <td style="width:16%">


                            <a rel="<?=$usuario->matricula?>" id="view" name="view" class="btn btn-default text-center" role="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span></a>

                                <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                                  <div class="modal-dialog">

                                    <!-- Modal content-->
                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                      <div class="modal-header">
                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                        <h3 class="modal-title"><?php echo $usuario->nome;?></h3>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="modal-body">
                                        <p>Matrícula: <?php echo $usuario->matricula;?></p>
                                        <p>Turma: <?php echo $usuario->turma;?></p>
                                        <p>Email: <?php echo $usuario->email;?></p>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="modal-footer">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                      </div>
                                    </div>

                                  </div>
                                </div>



                            <a href="#editar.php?matricula=<?=$usuario->matricula?>" class="btn btn-primary text-center" role="button" disabled><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>
                            <a href="#index.php?delete=<?=$usuario->matricula?>" class="btn btn-danger text-center" role="button" disabled><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>

                        </tr>   
                        <?php endforeach;?>
                    </table>
                    </div>


                    <?php else: ?>

                    <!-- Mensagem caso não exista clientes ou não encontrado  -->
                    <h5 class="text-center text-default">Não há registros cadastrados ou não correspondem à pesquisa!</h5>

                <?php endif; ?>

            </li>

        </ul>

    </div>

</body>
```

Códigos de inclusão, exclusão e pesquisa (nessa ordem) de usuários.

```
<?php 

$conexao = conexao::getInstance();

if(isset($_POST['inserir'])){
    $matricula = $_POST['matricula'];
    $nome = trim(strip_tags($_POST['nome']));
    $turma = trim(strip_tags($_POST['turma']));
    $email = trim(strip_tags($_POST['email']));
    $login = trim(strip_tags($_POST['login']));
    $senha = trim(strip_tags($_POST['senha']));
    $nivel = trim(strip_tags($_POST['nivel']));

    $insert = "INSERT into tab_usuarios (matricula, nome, turma, email, login, senha, nivel) VALUES (:matricula, :nome, :turma, :email, :login, :senha, :nivel)";

        try{
        $result = $conexao->prepare($insert);
        $result->bindParam(':matricula', $matricula, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $result->bindParam(':nome', $nome, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $result->bindParam(':turma', $turma, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $result->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $result->bindParam(':login', $login, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $result->bindParam(':senha', $senha, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $result->bindParam(':nivel', $nivel, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $result->execute();
        $count = $result->rowCount();

        if($count>0){
            echo '<div class="alert alert-success">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> <strong>Usuário cadastrado com sucesso!</strong>
                    </div>';

            echo "<meta http-equiv=refresh content='1;URL=index.php'>";//refresh da pagina

        }else{
        echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> <strong>Não foi possivel cadastrar o usuário</strong>
                </div>';

        echo "<meta http-equiv=refresh content='1;URL=index.php'>";//refresh da pagina

        }

        }catch(PDOException $e){
                echo $e;
            }
}?>


<?php 

//exclusão de usuário
$conexao = conexao::getInstance();

if(isset($_GET['delete'])){
    $matricula = $_GET['delete'];

    $del = "DELETE from tab_usuarios WHERE matricula=:matricula";

    try{
        $result = $conexao->prepare($del);
        $result->bindParam(':matricula',$matricula, PDO::PARAM_INT);                
        $result->execute();
        $count = $result->rowCount();
        if($count>0){
            echo '<div class="alert alert-success">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> <strong>Usuário deletado com sucesso!</strong>
                </div>';

            echo "<meta http-equiv=refresh content='1;URL=index.php'>";//refresh da pagina

            }else{
                echo '<div class="alert alert-msgstatus alert-danger alert-dismissable col-md-6 col-xs-6 col-6 col-md-offset-3  col-xs-offset-3 col-offset-3">
                        <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
                        <strong>Houve um erro ao deletar o cadastro.</strong>
                    </div>';    

            echo "<meta http-equiv=refresh content='1;URL=index.php'>";//refresh da pagina
        }

    }catch (PDOWException $erro){ echo $erro;}
}?>

<?php

// Recebe o termo de pesquisa se existir
$termo = (isset($_GET['termo'])) ? $_GET['termo'] : '';

// Verifica se o termo de pesquisa está vazio, se estiver executa uma consulta completa
if (empty($termo)):


    $conexao = conexao::getInstance();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tab_usuarios ORDER BY nome ASC "; //LIMIT $inicio, $quantidade
    $stm = $conexao->prepare($sql);
    $stm->execute();
    $usuarios = $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

else:

    // Executa uma consulta baseada no termo de pesquisa passado como parâmetro
    $conexao = conexao::getInstance();
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM tab_usuarios WHERE nome LIKE :nome OR matricula LIKE :matricula OR turma LIKE :turma ORDER BY nome ASC ';
    $stm = $conexao->prepare($sql);
    $stm->bindValue(':nome', $termo.'%');
    $stm->bindValue(':matricula', $termo.'%');
    $stm->bindValue(':turma', $termo.'%');
    $stm->execute();
    $usuarios = $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

endif; ?>
```

Caso necessitem, posso estar disponibilizando um compactado com os arquivos do trabalho para facilitar. Agradeço desde já e desculpe-me a falta de habilidade.

Comment: F12 e veja o conteúdo de seu HTML, mas já adianto que você está criando vários modais no seu foreach quando o ideal seria criar apenas um ai quando for abrir carregar os dados.

Comment: @NelsonAguiar obrigado por avisar.
Aqui está a print com o conteúdo HTML.

http://prntscr.com/eds484

Comment: Como disse você está criando mais de um modal e todos com o  mesmo id, esse é o problema, quando chama o id ele ira abrir o primeiro que encontrar com o aquele id, teria que colocar um id diferente para cada modal o que não é recomendável, pois você criaria um modal para cada registro, seria muito código  gerado sem necessidade,  ideal seria criar apenas um ai quando for abrir carregar os dados seja com ajax o que acho mais conveniente ou jogar o próprio usuário que vem do PHP por  parâmetro.

Comment: Entendi @NelsonAguiar. Obrigado! :)